# Where to get the bookmark/folder/history icons used by MobileSafari?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

where can I get the bookmark/folder/history icons used by MobileSafari? I tried to copy them from MobielSafari.app but unfortunately those icons cant be opened. It seems they are encrypted.

Comment: As they should be...why are you trying to steal from another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that creating a UImage with the name Bookmark.png will give you the ios bookmark icon. 
However not sure about history and folders. Tried History.png ... no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but for similar icons be sure to check:

- **Glyphish**: Free for non-retina, $25 for retina versions: http://www.greepit.com/open-source-icons-gcons/
- **GLYPHICONS**: Free for non-retina, $25 for retina, $50 for retina+vector version: http://glyphicons.com/
- **gcons**: Free: http://www.greepit.com/open-source-icons-gcons/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the sitting, scroll down> safari, scroll down> history
Good luck